# Proceso, procezo (kaj ankaŭ procedo, proceduro). Kiun uzi?

Tags: word-usage

Mi trovis en vortaroj la vortojn *proceso* kaj *procezo*. Se oni aldonas similajn vortojn kiel *procedo* (el *procedi*) kaj *proceduro*, la afero elekti la plej taŭgan fariĝas tre malsimpla.

Vortaroj (ekz.: http://vortaro.net/#procezo kaj http://reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/procez.html#procez.0o) diras ke *procezo* povas egali al *proceso* kaj *procedo*.

Kiel oni povas trovi la plej taŭgan en ĉiu aparta situacio, se ili ĉiuj estas parte sinonimaj?

Mi rimarkis ankaŭ ke *proceso* estas fundamenta kaj *procezo* estas en neniu oficiala aldono. Mi scias ka la lingvo estas pli granda ol la oficialaj radikoj, kaj ke ReVo diras ke la vorto proceso ekster juro estas arkaismo. Tamen, la manko de oficiala aldono ŝajnas al mi kiel subtila indiko ke *procezo* estas ne-necesa por ĉiutaga (kaj komputila) lingvaĵo kaj oni povas uzi nur *proceso*.

Ĉu mia konkludo estas ĝusta? Aŭ ĉu la uzado de *procezo* jam estas tiel vasta ke ne eblas reunuigi tiun vortoparon?

Rimarko: mi pensas ke respondoj kiuj inkluzivas ankaŭ *procedo* kaj *proceduro* estas tiel bonvenaj kiel respondoj kiuj komentas nur pri *proceso* kaj *procezo*.

Answer (score 7):

Mi sugestas:

- *procedo* — metodo konduti aferon aŭ atingi celon ("method, proceedings")
- *proceduro* — formala metodo konduti aferon laŭ kutimoj aŭ leĝoj ("procedure")
- *proceso* — juĝafero antaŭ tribunalo ("trial") aŭ elstaraĵo de organo
- *procezo* — sinsekvo de fenomenoj ("a process")

Tiel *procedo* koncernas agojn, kaj *procezo* koncernas fenomenojn pli ĝenerale.

Proceduro estas speco de procedo, kaj procedo estas speco de procezo. Antaŭe oni uzis la vorton *proceso* por *procezo*, sed tio nun eviteblas.

Aldone, ekzistas la vortoj:

- *procesio* — ceremonia marŝo
- *procesoro* — centra parto de komputilo

"To process" estas *prilabori, trakti*.

Comment: Ho, nun mi rememoris ke tiu dubo aperis antaŭ kelkaj jaroj kiam mi bezonis decidi inter procesoro kaj procezilo (kial unu havas S kaj la alia havas Z?)... Se necese mi kreos novan demandon pri tio.

Comment: Tiu difino de proceso = rilata al tribunalo aŭ organo estas stranga kaj amuza, ĉu ne? Kio estas komuna inter tiuj du signifoj? :-)